# Slow application serving domestic and foreign users

Tags: performance, terminal-services

We have an application monitoring remote workers, which recently become increasingly slow. Some users connect using a Client on their office PCs, others from home (within the same city) and third group connects from abroad using Terminal Services. Do you have any idea what may be causing the problem?

Comment: Gremlins, most likely...

Comment: We checked and Gremlins and other similar creatures weren't involved :-) On a more serious note, we are running out of ideas. Any help anyone?

Comment: The (unstated) point is that there's really not anywhere near enough information to even offer an uneducated guess here. And even if there were, it's not particularly related to programming, which is what questions on this site are intended to be about...